# Login Succeeded But Authorization Failed ASP.NET CORE

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have added authentication to my asp.net core application as below

```
var authenticationBuilder = services.AddAuthentication(builder =>
{
   builder.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
   builder.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
});

authenticationBuilder.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
    options.Cookie.Name = $"{AppCookieDefaults.Prefix}{AppCookieDefaults.AuthenticationCookie}";
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
});
```

When i tried to login using `SignInManager` `PasswordSignInAsync` my login was successful but Application still redirect to login page when i check console it shows

[image]

And it seems authentication cookie also not renamed the way i wanted.

[image]

I cannot figure it out what went wrong

**Update**

I added  `authenticationBuilder.AddIdentityCookies` Instead calling `AddCookie`

Surly i guess i messed up something while registering service for info i will update here is code i'm registering identity

```
services.AddIdentityCore<User>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddUserManager<UserManager<User>>()
    .AddSignInManager()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
   options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
   options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
   options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
   options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
   options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
   options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
   options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
   options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
   options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = false;
   options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Core Identity will include the Cookie Authentication middleware on the pipeline. So you don't need to create separate Cookie Authentication middleware when you are using ASP.NET Core Identity.

If you want to config the cookie settings , you can configure the app's cookie in Startup.ConfigureServices. `ConfigureApplicationCookie` must be called after calling `AddIdentity` or `AddDefaultIdentity`.

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
    options.Cookie.Name = $"{AppCookieDefaults.Prefix}{AppCookieDefaults.AuthenticationCookie}";
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
});
```

Please refer to [Configure ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for more details .

Comment: Show us your entire service config .

Comment: thanks Nan Yu i have updated the question . could you please have a look

Comment: Do you have any authorization config , if not , the simplest way is to create a new app using asp.net identity template and then compare the difference with your current app.

Comment: actually IsAutheticate getting false when I add hangfire dashboard authorizationfile `IDashboardAuthorizationFilter` `context.GetHttpContext()?.User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated ?? false` inside other controllers it's getting true